# Can you use autorun.inf on an SD card on Windows 8+?

Tags: autorun

I need to be able to use an autorun.inf file in windows 8, I am aware that Microsoft has disabled auto run on USBs, but would this still work on an SD card, and would it work the same way?

Comment: look at this answer http://superuser.com/questions/794523/autorun-inf-in-windows-8-8-1-for-usb-drives